# Remove the last pipe from a text file

Tags: powershell-3.0

**Objective:** I need to remove the last `|` from a file, only if it is truly the last `\w` character in the file.

Why does the following syntax append instead of replacing?

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\example.txt") -replace '`|$','' > .\example.txt
```

I also tried

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\example.txt") -replace '\|$','' > .\example.txt
```

...which doesn't do anything, it seems. Not surprisingly, the equivalent with `Get-Content` doesn't work either:

```
(Get-Content .\example.txt) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '$\|', ''} | Set-Content .\example.txt
```

I assume it is some issue with properly parsing the pipe, but I am uncertain how to compensate for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help in #powershell on Freenode, I have it now.

```
$Content = Get-Content example.txt;
If ($Content[-1] -eq '|') {
    $Content.Substring(0,$Content.Length-1) > example.txt
}
```